# PDO Sqlite error 5: database locked

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I've been trying to use a sqlite database (php with PDO), but have been running into a problem. Generally the commands work, and everything is fine (including storing files), but for some reason when I run these two commands (which have been simplified), I get the error

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 5 database is locked

I've tried for a while, but have been unable to fix whatever is wrong. The code is below.

Things I've done: 
  Tried to put sleep(2) between commands
  Found out that commenting either of the commands out will cause the error not to happen (which doesn't really help, as both commands must run)

Note that (unlike other problems I saw while looking at similar questions) the database operates correctly in other cases.

```
$db = new MyDB();

$STH = $db->catchMistakes('SELECT PASSWORD FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME = ?', "test");

$STH->fetchColumn();

$db->catchMistakes("UPDATE ISSUES SET NAME = ? WHERE NUM = ?", ["test", "1"]);
```

And here's the code for MyDB

```
public function catchMistakes($cmd, $params = []) {

   if (!is_array($params)) {
       $params = [$params];
   }

    try {

        $DBH = new PDO("sqlite:" . DB);
        $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

        $DBH->beginTransaction();


        $query = $DBH->prepare($cmd);


        $toReturn = $query->execute($params);

        $DBH->commit();


        return $query;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {

        $DBH->rollback();

        $error = $e->getMessage();

        exit;
    }

}
```

Sorry if there's a simple fix, I'm pretty new at this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using `closeCursor()`?

Comment: @frz3993 Thanks! Didn't know that existed. Change the comment to an answer and I'll mark it as such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `closeCursor()` method on a PDOStatement object to free the connection to the database so the statement can be executed. [You can refer to the PHP manual.](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php)